# How to set file size limit in Flask-WTF's FileField?

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms

How can I set FileSizeLimit validation for [`flask_wtf.file.FileField`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.file.FileField)?

Answer (score 4):

We need to add a custom validator like this:

```py
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

def FileSizeLimit(max_size_in_mb):
    max_bytes = max_size_in_mb*1024*1024
    def file_length_check(form, field):
        if len(field.data.read()) > max_bytes:
            raise ValidationError(f"File size must be less than {max_size_in_mb}MB")
        field.data.seek(0)
    return file_length_check
```

Then pass the validator to the file uploader field like this:

```py
uploaded_file = FileField('Upload your file', [FileRequired(), FileSizeLimit(max_size_in_mb=2)])
```

---

Credits:

Thanks to [@yomajo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11537568/yomajo) [for pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72902058) how to reset the filestream pointer after measuring the filesize.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer works to validate, but will fail when actually saving the file, due to exhausted file stream in size validation at `len(field.data.read())`

To save someone's hours, what I actually ended up with:

```
def FileSizeLimit(max_size_in_mb):
    max_bytes = max_size_in_mb*1024*1024

    def file_length_check(form, field):
        if len(field.data.read()) > max_bytes:
            raise ValidationError(
                f'File size is too large. Max allowed: {max_size_in_mb} MB')
        field.data.seek(0)
    return file_length_check
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']

```
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = limit_in_mb * 1024 * 1024
```